# Why can't I use TypeScript 1.8 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

I downloaded and installed [TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593). The installer completed successfully, but "Help -> About" does not show anything TypeScript-related, and "Add -> New Item... Scripts" only has JavaScript and CoffeeScript. I can see that TypeScript installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8 and it works fine from a normal command line, but Visual Studio seems to know nothing about it.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least Visual Studio Update 1 (maybe higher), but the TypeScript 1.8 installer does not tell you this.

I figured this out by trying to install TypeScript 1.7. This installer gave an error saying that Visual Studio Update 1 was needed before I could continue. I just installed [Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs), assuming it would include updates 1 and 2. Now TypeScript 1.8 seems to be working just fine.